# JW Player integreation in Adobe Air desktop Application

Tags: air, adobe, jwplayer

we have an desktop application built in adobe air application. which is having feature to play using the online steaming from web application and also having capability to play the downloaded video in local drive of the PC and Mac

Now, we want to use JW player for steaming and playing video from localdrive ..

Can we integrate JW player in Adobe Air application ?

Please let us know if you have any information on this.

Thanks,
Mayur

Comment: This isn't something we support, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to do that. JW Player is a Javascript-dependent steering script intended to operate within a browser. It's relying on the browser's own native `<video>` tag ability to actually play the video. For RTMP streaming, it's calling the browser's Flash plugin. So I don't think there's any way to incorporate JW Player into a standalone application.